# Get list of document I’d present inside a collection in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named `requests` and inside that collection I have many Document. I want to get the Id of each document present inside that collection

Answer (score 1):

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection(FirebaseCollection.user)
    .where(UserCollectionField.mobile, isEqualTo: mobile)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((snapshot) {
      var id = snapshot.documents[0].documentID;

}).catchError((error) {

});
```

also you can make list of user id ex.

```
 Firestore.instance
        .collection(FirebaseCollection.user)
        .where(UserCollectionField.mobile, isEqualTo: mobile)
        .getDocuments()
            .then((querySnapshot) async {
          var list = querySnapshot.documents;
          list.forEach((document) {
            adminlist.add(document.documentID);
          });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest but I need all documents present 

Comment: If you know the way kindly suggest

Comment: if possible then share your code sample to best understanding.